# How to show a at scheduled command?

Tags: cron, at

Say I want to have a beep at 13:00. I would use

```
speaker-test -t sine -f 1300 | at 13:00
```

I can find that something is going to be executed with `atq` but **how to get the precise scheduled command?** (that is   `speaker-test -t sine -f 1300`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
atq
```

will list the jobs:

```
4   Mon Apr 24 15:00:00 2017 a skitt
```

The first number is the job identifier, which you can then use with `at -c` to view the job’s contents:

```
at -c 4
```

Note that `at` jobs start with a lengthy setup to reproduce the environment in which the job was defined; you’ll see the command you gave at the end.